# NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{XY6cYmf7Sn-DRZgzeq3PBA}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]]

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am using BULK API of elasticsearch with version 5.6.16 of Elasticsearch and KIbana both.
The following code is working fine and uploading the code to an index of ES.

these are dependencies that I currently have.

> implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch'
>
> compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'transport'
>
> compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.plugin', name: 'transport-netty4-client'

```
@Service
public class BulkApiService {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BulkApiService.class);
    private String FOLDER_PATH = "src/main/resources/allRecipesJson";
    private String index = "test";

    @Autowired
    ElasticSearchConfig elasticSearchConfig;

    public String loadBulkData() throws UnknownHostException {
        Client client = elasticSearchConfig.client();
        AtomicReference<BulkRequestBuilder> request = new AtomicReference<>(client.prepareBulk());
        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        try (Stream<Path> filePathStream = Files.walk(Paths.get(FOLDER_PATH))) {
            filePathStream.forEach(filePath -> {
                if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
                    counter.getAndIncrement();
                    try {
                        String content = Files.readString(filePath);
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(content);
                        HashMap yourHashMap1 = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject1.toString(), HashMap.class);
                        request.get().add(client.prepareIndex(index, "default").setSource(yourHashMap1));

                    } catch (IOException ignore) {
                        log.error(ignore.toString());

                    }

                }
            });
            BulkResponse bulkResponse = request.get().execute().actionGet();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.toString());
        }

        return "Bulk data loaded to index " + index + "";
    }
```

Following is the configuration

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchConfig {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElasticSearchConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public Client client() {
        TransportClient client = null;
        try {
            client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
                    .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            log.error(log.toString());
        }
        return client;
    }
}
```

Now I want to move to Elasticserch and Kibana version 7.3.1.
I am unable to load the data to the elasticsearch index. The following error is shown on IDE Log

> service.BulkApiService - NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{XY6cYmf7Sn-DRZgzeq3PBA}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]]

The error on elasticsearch imagec

Kindly help me to correct it.

Comment: Do you need to use the transport layer? The recommended is via http now

Comment: @AlkisKalogeris can you please update your answer with HTTP so that my main objective meet . I wanna use BULK Api of ELK using java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the correct code.

```
@Service
public class BulkApiService { private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BulkApiService.class);
    private String FOLDER_PATH = "src/main/resources/allRecipesJson";
    private String index = "test1";
    private static final String TYPE = "test_type";


    @Autowired
    private RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;

    public String loadBulkData() throws IOException {

        BulkRequest bulkRequest = new BulkRequest();
        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        try (Stream<Path> filePathStream = Files.walk(Paths.get(FOLDER_PATH))) {
            filePathStream.forEach(filePath -> {
                if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
                    counter.getAndIncrement();
                    System.out.println(filePath.toFile().getAbsoluteFile().toString());
                    try {
                        String content = Files.readString(filePath);
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(content);
                        HashMap yourHashMap1 = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject1.toString(), HashMap.class);
                        IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(index, TYPE).source(yourHashMap1);
                        bulkRequest.add(indexRequest);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            });
        }
        try {
            restHighLevelClient.bulk(bulkRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Bulk data loaded to index " + index + "";
    }
}
```

Add the following dependency and remove the already placed dependencies.

> compile 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.4.2'